# Storing decimal numbers from a text file to an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, storing-data

I'm trying to store 10 decimal numbers from a text file into an array. My problem is that it is skipping several numbers until it reaches the end of line.

I debugged the program by printing out the number of cycles the program took for reaching the end of the file, and resulted 10. And it is the correct value of how many numbers there are in the file. But when I display the element values of the array, only 5 numbers are there. When I compare the stored numbers with the text file numbers, It results that several numbers are being skipped.

Here is my code below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(void) 
{
   FILE *inp;         /* pointer to input file */

   double item;
   int cnt=0,y,d,i;
   double array[300],swap;  

   /* Prepare files for input */
   inp = fopen("C:/Users/infile.txt", "r");


   /* Read each item */
   while ( (fscanf(inp, "%lf", &item) == 1) && (!feof(inp)) ) {
     array[cnt] = item;
     cnt++; 
   }


   for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
   {
      printf("%lf\n",array[i]);
      i++;
   }
   printf("%d",cnt);


  fclose(inp); /* Close the files */

  return (0);
}
```

-In the text file there are 10 double numbers ranging from 0 to 101 (ex 15.12563)

-The value for the cycle times of the while loop is 10 (cnt reaches 10)

-My code only stores 5 numbers instead of 10, which is skipping the rest 5 numbers, but it says it has reached the last value at line 10.

These are the values in the text file:

21.388000

12.372628

21.961366

85.616285

30.123001

30.271053

70.733982

35.867327

48.339462

82.459009

If I left some key information about my concern please ask. Thanks

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with fewer than 101 numbers? If so, with what numbers? Include them in the question itself so that it is a [mcve].

Comment: I modified the question @JohnColeman , and yes, the problem still occurs using a shorter list of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple problem

You store the values correctly. The error is in your printing cycle.
You increment the `i` two times. Please delete the `i++;` from second cycle.

I tested it, and it works well

Comment: you are right. Thanks for your time and sorry for the newbie mistake